# Call aspx web service/page from classic asp https:// site on the same server

Tags: .net, ajax

I've got an ASP app running under SSL that I want to extend by using JQuery/Ajax and thought I'd write the methods that are called by it in .NET, hosted on the same server. How do I set it up? Should it be within the SSL domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://www.sonerdy.com/post/2008/10/21/JQuery-AJAX-and-ASMX.aspx). Decorate the web service with the `[ScriptService]` attribute and then invoke it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/WebserviceName.asmx/MethodName',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        Parameter1: 'foo', 
        Parameter2: 'bar'
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) { 
        // TODO: do something with the result
    }
});
```

You could do the same with an ASPX page with [PageMethods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

The only requirement is that the client is hosted on the same domain and it doesn't violate the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So for example if the .NET page is hosted on HTTPS and your client page on HTTP you cannot send AJAX requests (that's considered as a violation of the same origin policy).

Comment: But I could have a .net application set up in the same domain space as the classic asp app? I'm a little fuzzy on configuration. We have a server with a site at mysite.domain.com and it points to the classic asp app, which is under SSL. Where would I put the .NET app to have it under the same area?

Comment: @Caveatrob, StackOverflow is a programming related Q&A. Server configuration questions are better suited on http://serverfault.com

Comment: I'm wondering about that. What are the chances the serverfault people will know about programming issues that require a server configuration like this? Most of the people in my experience were always developers. I'm not asking for an elaborate thing - just a basic tip.